# How to use stream as where clause with Spring data jpa?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.4.RELEASE` in my springboot application. I tried few scenarios where I'd build a query using the query builder feature. eg -

```
@Query(value="select new Foo(b.name) from Bar b where b.id IN (:ids)")
Stream<Foo> findByIdIn(@Param("ids")List<String> ids);
```

Is it possible to use streams in the where clause? something like eg - `Stream<Foo> findByIdIn(Stream<String> ids)`. If its possible then how should I change :ids in my @Query?

Can someone point me to an example ?

Comment: In my knowledge No . You can't  but you can return as a stream.

Comment: What does happen when you change the parameter type to `Stream<String>`?